# How to slip gather-take in lazy manner into map?

Tags: memory-leaks, lazy-evaluation, raku, lazy-sequences, rakudo

I need to construct following flow:

- Accept list of file names
- Extract multiple lines from those files
- Process those lines

However I have no idea how to properly inject `gather`-`take` into `map`:

```raku
sub MAIN ( *@file-names ) {

    @file-names.map( { slip parse-file( $_ ) } ).map( { process-line( $_ ) } );
}

sub parse-file ( $file-name ) {
    return gather for $file-name.IO.lines -> $line {
        take $line if $line ~~ /a/; # dummy example logic
    }
}

sub process-line ( $line ) {
    say $line;  # dummy example logic
}
```

This code works but leaks memory like crazy. I assume `slip` makes `gather`-`take` eager? Or `slip` does not mark `Seq` items as consumed? **Is there a way to slip `gather`-`take` result into `map` in lazy manner?**

BTW: My intent is to parallelize each step with `race` later - so for example I have 2 files parsed at the same time producing lines for 10 line processors. Generally speaking I'm trying to figure out easiest way of composing such cascade flows. I've tried Channels to connect each processing step but they have no built-in pushback. If you have any other   patterns for such flows then comments are more than welcomed.

**EDIT 1:**

I think my code is correct, and memory leak is not caused by bad logic but rather by bug in Slip class. I've created issue https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/5138 that is currently open. I'll post an update once it is resolved.

**EDIT 2:**
No, my code was not correct :) Check for my post for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - I had big misconception. I thought that all lines produced by `parse-file` must be slipped into map `block` like this:

```
@file-names.map( produce all lines here ).map( process all lines here );
```

And `Slip` is a `List` that tracks all elements. That is why I had big memory leak.

**The solution is to create `gather`-`take` sequence inside `map` but consume it outside `map`**:

```perl
@file-names.map( { parse-file( $_ ) } ).flat.map( { process-line( $_ ) } );
```

So now it is:

```
@file-names.map( construct sequence here ).(get items from sequence here).map( process all lines here );
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe that you are mistaken about the cause of the non-laziness in your code – in general, using `slip` should not typically make code eager.  And, indeed, when I run the slightly modified version of your code shown below:

```raku
sub MAIN () {
    my @file-names = "tmp-file000".."tmp-file009";
    spurt $_, ('a'..'z').join("\n") for @file-names;

    my $parsed = @file-names.map( { slip parse-file( $_ ) } );
    say "Reached line $?LINE";

    $parsed.map( { process-line( $_ ) } );
}

sub parse-file ( $file-name ) {
    say "processing $file-name...";
    gather for $file-name.IO.lines -> $line {
        take $line if $line ~~ /a/; # dummy example logic
    }
}

sub process-line ( $line ) {
    say $line;  # dummy example logic
}
```

I get the output that shows Raku processing the files lazily (note that it does not call `parse-file` until it needs to pass new values to `process-line`):

```
Reached 8
processing tmp-file000...
a
processing tmp-file001...
a
processing tmp-file002...
a
processing tmp-file003...
a
processing tmp-file004...
a
processing tmp-file005...
a
processing tmp-file006...
a
processing tmp-file007...
a
processing tmp-file008...
a
processing tmp-file009...
a
```

Since I don't have the rest of your code, I'm not sure what is triggering the non-lazy behavior you're observing.  In general, if you have code that is being eagerly evaluated when you want it to be lazy, though, the [`.lazy`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/lazy) method and/or the [`lazy` statement prefixes](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/lazy) are good tools.

---

Finally, a couple of minor notes about the code you posted that aren't relevant to your question but that might be helpful:

1. All Raku functions return their final expression, so the `return` statement in `parse-file` isn't necessary (and it's actually slightly slower/non-idiomatic).
2. A big part of the power of `gather`/`take` is that they can cross function boundaries.  That is, you can have a `parse-file` function that `take`s different lines without needing to have the `gather` statement inside `parse-lines` – you just need to call `parse-lines` within the scope of a `gather` block.  This *feels* like it might be helpful in solving the problem you're working on, though it's hard to be sure without more info.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I have no idea why on long files I have results printed right away (meaning non-lazy manner, just as you observed) and at the same time I get huge memory leak. But you inspired me with this cross boundaries `gather`-`take` idea. Indeed file parser is lines provider, not lines consumer. Maybe I'll figure something out using this method.

Comment: Also: `gather for $file-name.IO.lines -> $line { take $line if $line ~~ /a/ }` is just a complicated way of doing `$file-name.IO.lines.map: -> $line { $line if $line ~~ /a/ }`.  The latter being about 3x as fast.  Whether that matters, of course depends on the complexity of your condition.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen and, in turn, `$file-name.IO.lines.map: -> $line { $line if $line ~~ /a/ }` is just a complicated way of doing `$file-name.IO.lines.grep(/a/)`  :D

Comment: I think this is Raku bug: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/5138 . Looks like my code is correct but slip leaks memory when used on lazy sequence.

Comment: As for simplification suggestions - @Elizabeth Mattijsen is right, but those are just dummy examples. My real logic in file parsing is way more complex.

Comment: @codesections yes, indeed, but since @Pawel suggested some complicated checking logic, I kept the `.map`